# Animate curved Path to another Path

Tags: android, android-animation

I have to animate a curved Path to some other positions of the points of the Path. I am using cubicTo and five points like this:

```
    Path mainFillPath = new Path();
    mainFillPath.reset();
    mainFillPath.moveTo(leftPointX, leftPointY);

    mainFillPath.cubicTo(leftPointX, leftPointY, centerPointX1, centerPointY1, centerPointX, centerPointY);
    mainFillPath.cubicTo(centerPointX, centerPointY, centerPointX2, centerPointY2, rightPointX, rightPointY);

    mainFillPath.lineTo(rightPointX, 0);
    mainFillPath.lineTo(0, 0);

    mainFillPath.close();
```

I am painting on canvas   `canvas.drawPath(myPath, paint);`

What Animator I have to use to have this wave result:

[image: path to path]

I have tried ObjectAnimator and ValueAnimator from some projects. One of them is using PathEvaluator() to animate a moving Button on certain Path like this:

```
    final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "buttonLoc",
            new PathEvaluator(), path.getPoints().toArray());
    anim.setDuration(2000);
```

Comment: Hi did you solve that problem?
if you did, can you share your solution?
here, or to email? 
artemenkobogdan@gmail.com